# Unable to access an object in include partials in EJS template

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm trying to send an object to an aside menu which is present in all the EJS templates in my app.

There are around 10 EJS templates which gets rendered by 10 router endpoints. Here's how a typical endpoint looks like:

```
router.get( "/example", ( req, res ) => {
    res.render( "../views/example.ejs" );
} );
```

In all the templates I have 3 `include` partials: `header, footer and aside menu`.

Here's how a typical template looks like:

```
<%- include ("./partials/header") %>

// some body content

<%- include ("./partials/asidemenu") %>

<%- include ("./partials/footer") %>
```

I have this array in the file system which consists of objects of data which I need to pass in the `asidemenu` template.

WHAT I TRIED SO FAR:

I fetched the data in the endpoints and put it in `res.render` as the second parameter:

`{ data: data }`

I have access to the data in the corresponding EJS template by using `<%= data %>` which I put in `include` partials as the second parameter:

`<%- include ("./partials/asidemenu", { data: <%= data %> }) %>`.

Then in `asidemenu.ejs`, I tried to access the data as `<%= data %>` but I get `data is undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: How does the asidemenu template look like?

Comment: Also check that data variable is not empty

Comment: It's a simple template. I wanted to use a property value of the first object in the ```data``` array by using ```<%= data[0].name %>```.

Comment: data variable is not empty as it is being fetched in the endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove interpolation tag when you passing the data variable to the include.

```
<%- include("./partials/asidemenu", { data: data }) %>
```

Comment: hey. Getting ```data is not defined```.  :(

Comment: Oh, looks like you misses the data when you are calling the render function. You need to speficy the second parameter when you are calling render function. `res.render("../views/example.ejs", { data })`

Comment: No. I showed how an endpoint looks like. I actually used that in my code. I also mentioned it later in the post.

Comment: Oops. I actually put ```{ data: data }``` somewhere else. Lol. What a stupid mistake. Just spent 2 hours finding the mistake. Anyway Thanks mate.